# Form processing with coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, coffeescript

This seems like one of the most common coffeescript thigns to do and yet after extensive searching on stackoverflow and on google, I can't find any example of it.

For various reasons, I'm trying to have a standard rails form submit be handled by coffeescript.  Imagine a form (generated by rails) for a User class with a name (string), age (integer), and birthday (date)--so the form has the field objects named.

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('form').submit ->
    name = form.name.value
    age = form.age.value
    birthday = form.birthday.value
    User.create(:name => name, :age => age, :birthday => birthday)
```

One other catch, I want it to render a different page instead of /user/ and I'm unclear how to do that.

I've tried out the code but can't seem to capture the values. I figured there would be some example online but after many different search attempts I couldn't find anything.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into a client side framework like [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)

This will let you modify javascript representations of your model and sync it with your rails app through a restful api.